# Python twisted dataReceived method receive complete data at once

Tags: python, twisted

This is my code
`

```
class TestProtocol(Protocol):
    def connectionMade(self):
        print 'Got connection from', self.transport.client

    def dataReceived(self, data):
            print(data)


class Test(Factory, HoneypotService):
    NAME = 'test'
    protocol = TestProtocol

    def __init__(self, config=None, logger=None):
        HoneypotService.__init__(self, config=config, logger=logger)
        self.port = 8888

    def getService(self):
        return internet.TCPServer(self.port, self)
```

When I use the `telnet 127.0.0.1 8888`  command to connect to this service, and input `abcdef`,Method dataReceived is executed twice,execute result is as follows:

output picture:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62ov7.png)

Is there any way to execute dataReceived only once, And the output information is `abcdef`.
I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

The output information is `abcdef`.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the Twisted FAQ:

> TCP is a stream-oriented transport. This means that when you call `transport.write`, the data may be broken up into arbitrarily-sized chunks for transmission over the network. There is no way for Twisted to determine how large the data originally written to the transport was.
>
> If you want to send a message and receive it whole on the other end of a connection, you must decide on a format for the message and parse it. For example, prefixing the message with a length or terminating it with a message boundary.

https://github.com/twisted/trac-wiki-archive/blob/trunk/FrequentlyAskedQuestions.mediawiki#why-is-protocoldatareceived-called-with-only-part-of-the-data-i-called-transportwrite-with

Comment: I see what you mean and read Twisted FAQ,But there's no example of how to use rawDataReceived。I change my code
   ‘’ def dataReceived(self, data):

        self._buffer += data
        if self._busyReceiving:
            return

        try:
            self._busyReceiving = True
            print "_buffer", self._buffer
        finally:
            self._busyReceiving = False
‘’
output result ：The dataReceived method is executed twice

Comment: When I rewrite rawDataReceived, it doesn't trigger it

Comment: I can't read the code in that comment because of how it is formatted.  I don't know why you are getting rawDataReceived involved though.

Comment: use raw mode of  receiver,Received complete data 'abcedf'.

Comment: Nope.  That's not what "raw" mode of *LineReceiver* (not *Protocol*) does.

Comment: How can I use "raw" mode，I just want Received complete data 'abcedf'

Comment: You're already in raw mode.  That's why you don't receive the whole chunk of data that you want at once.  You need a framing protocol so you can assemble sub-chunks into whole chunks.  You didn't mention what you're trying to accomplish so I don't know what framing protocol you're using, or what would be appropriate to add to your application.